# How to convert attributes to nodes of an xml in java?

Tags: java, xml

I am parsing an XML file like

```
<STRUCTURE ID="EV_Se96ffb9a-df1f-44e7-a4f8-818688cf8d3b">
      <SHORT-NAME>STRUCT</SHORT-NAME>
      <LONG-NAME>Structure</LONG-NAME>
</STRUCTURE>
```

where I am getting the child nodes of STRUCTURE and adding it to a nodeList.

Can I have an option to add the attributes of STRUCTURE i.e, ID to a nodeList ?

How to convert the attributes to a node and add it to a nodelist ?
Please help me out.

I am using the DOM parsing strategy

Answer (score 0):

The `Node` class has a method `getAttributes()` which returns a `NamedNodeMap`. Of course, only elements will return an appropriate named node map (as only elements can have attributes).

On such a `NamedNodeMap` you can then retrieve the attribute node via a call to `getNamedItem(String)` or via a call to `item(int)`. Note, that the return type of these methods is a `Node`, which - in case of attributes - will in fact be an `Attr`.